# How to add Authorized redirect URIs and Authorized JavaScript origins url programmatically in terraform

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

```js
resource "google_iap_client" "client" {
  display_name = "Test Client"
  brand        =  "gcp test"
}
```

Im working with terraform and trying to create OAuth Client ID but I'm unable to add Authorized redirect URIs and Authorized JavaScript origins url programmatically in terraform.

I don't find this option in gcloud too. Is there a way I can use shell script for this or is there any other way? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly it's not possible through the provider yet (https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/15786).

The provider cannot offer this until there is an API for this (https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/6074#issuecomment-647686999).

Hence: it has to be done manually.